# ¿Por qué no funciona el operador ternario en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) (aunque mi pregunta es válida para javascript en general) y me topé con algo que no entiendo.

Está relacionado con el [operador ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario) el cual *según entiendo*, funciona así:

```
var numero = 5;
var positivo = numero >= 0 ? true : false;
```

Si la condición (`numero >=0`) se cumple, el resultado final será el primer valor que aparece luego de dicha condición, en este caso `true`. En caso contrario, el resultado final será el segundo valor, en este caso `false`.

Por lo que al imprimir:

```
console.log(positivo); //imprime true
```

Si cambio la variable `numero`, puedo obtener un valor falso:

```
var numero = -1;
var positivo = numero >= 0 ? true : false; 
console.log(positivo); //imprime false
```

Hasta ahora todo bien, pero tratando de aislar mi problema hice este pequeño fragmento de código:

```
var isValid = false;
var message;

if(isValid){
  message = 'es válida';
}else {
  message = 'no es válida';
}

console.log("Ésta condición " + message);
console.log("Ésta condición " + isValid ? 'es válida' : 'no es válida');
```

Según mi lógica, dado que en mi código la variable `isValid` es falsa, ambos mensajes deberían imprimir:

```
Ésta condición no es válida
```

Sin embargo cuando ejecuto mi programa el resultado es este:

```
Ésta condición no es válida
es válida
```

Como pueden ver, al usar el operador ternario ha ignorado por alguna razón que mi variable `isValid` estaba en `false`, ¿alguien tiene idea del por qué pasa esto? Y si fuera un comportamiento esperado (lo cual dudo) me gustaría saber el por qué.

Comment: Una observación: ¿No es redundante `numero >= 0 ? true : false`? Si al hacer `numero >= 0` retorna `true` o `false`, dependiendo de la condición. El uso operador ternario ahí esta mal. Con hacer `var positivo = numero >= 0;` ya debería bastar.

Comment: Era sólo un ejemplo sencillo para explicar el funcionamiento.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Debes utilizar paréntesis:

```
console.log("Ésta condición " + (isValid ? 'es válida' : 'no es válida'));
```

El operador `+` toma precedencia. Lo que el compilador entiende es lo siguiente:

```
console.log(("Ésta condición " + isValid) ? 'es válida' : 'no es válida');
```

Entonces imprime:

```
es valida
```

Dado que `"Ésta condición " + isValid` se evalúa como `true`.

---

Por cierto, este orden de precedencia se aplica a la mayoría de los lenguajes (honestamente, no se si hay alguno en que sea al revez), incluido JavaScript.

Esta es la tabla completa de precedencia de operadores en JavaScript (ver en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operator_Precedence)).

Comment: Gracias, he editado para que no parezca que es sólo de nodejs.

Comment: conforme avanzo en mis estudios sobre JavaScript, me doy cuenta que es bien extraño, en especial si venimos desde algún lenguaje fuertemente tipado como C# o Java. Intenta correr esto:
var obj = { calc: 'Logical AND' }; var value = obj && 99; console.log(value); //Aqui mi mente explotó x.x compilen mentalmente el resultado. Hay otros casos donde las validaciones de true y false rompen esquemas... y bueno, seguimos con todo el power 2.0!

Answer (score 2):

El resultado no es exáctamente el que dices. El resultado real es:

```
Ésta condición no es válida
es válida
```

Esto es porque el operador + tiene precedencia sobre ?. Lo que haces es primero concatenar `"Ésta condición " + isValid` y luego comprobar el resultado de esa concatenación para la condición del operador ternario. Como en javascript una cadena no vacía es verdadera, pone "es válida".

Comment: Lo había puesto mal pero ya lo edité. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Ocurren dos cosas:

- La primera es que como bien dicen en los comentarios anteriores, el operador `+` tiene más prioridad en esa expresión por lo que lo primero que hace es sumar y luego aplica el operador ternario.
- JavaScript interpreta que la suma de un string no vacío y `false` es el propio string.

  ```
  var a = 'string' + false; // da como resultado 'string'
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript tiene a mi parecer un problema con las precedencias y su parser en sí... pues trata de hacer que todo compile y si algo no cuadra lo descarta.

Tu código se traduce como:

```
console.log <- detecta impresión a consola
"Ésta condición "<- detecta una cadena 
+ <- detecta un operador y lo resuelve como de concatenación procede a buscar elementos para hacer concatenación
isValid ? 'es válida' <- el parser detecta que hay una cadena y como el prototipo del operador de concatenación recibe cadena le concatena 'es valida'
```

Para solventar este problema de una manera elegante puedes usar los `string templates` de la siguiente manera:

```js
var isValid = true;
console.log(`Ésta condición ${ isValid ? 'es válida' : 'no es válida'}`);
$("#salida").append(`Ésta condición ${ isValid ? 'es válida' : 'no es válida'}`);
$("#salida").append('<br>');
isValid = false;
console.log(`Ésta condición ${ isValid ? 'es válida' : 'no es válida'}`);
$("#salida").append(`Ésta condición ${ isValid ? 'es válida' : 'no es válida'}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="salida"></div>
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva de ayuda.